Trying to find the name of a movie
I'm trying to track down the name of a movie. I watched this when I was a kid all a bit vague, but i'll give as much detail as possible.
Basically a gift is presented to a member of the royal family. It is a small caged troll / cyclops which when wound it dances. One day the cage is opened and the troll / cyclops escapes and becomes big (magically when not in the cage) and wreaks havoc. 
The way the creature was filmed was similar to Ray Harryhausen past work (ie stop animation). I remember watching it in the early 80s on tv but it was probably made much earlier than that. 
Any help tracking this down would be appreciated.
Thanks
